# Is primefaces live scrolling compatible with Lazy loading

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable where huge data sets need to be displayed.So i decided to go with primefaces live scrolling.I also got to know that to improve datatable performance with huge data sets we need to implement lazy loading.With reference to the primefaces showcase example 
[here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf),what i observed that there in the statement

> , a LazyDataModel needs to be implemented to query the datasource when pagination, sorting, filtering or **live scrolling** happens

live scrolling is mentioned but i cannot see the code to handle scrolling.It only has the code to handle sorting,filtering,row count and pagination.Can someone please clarify my confusion if both live scolling and lazy datamodel implementation are compatible with each other or should i add some code to handle live scrolling also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works exactly the same as if you were having a pagination.

Here's a small example:

***xhtml***

```
<p:dataTable var="user"
        value="#{bean.lazyDataModel}"
        scrollRows="20"
        liveScroll="true"
        scrollHeight="500"
        lazy="true"
        scrollable="true">

        <p:column headerText="name">
           <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
        </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

***Bean***

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private LazyDataModel<User> lazyDataModel;

    @EJB
    UserEJB userEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       lazyDataModel = new LazyUserModel(userEJB);
    }

    public LazyDataModel<User> getLazyDataModel() {
        return lazyDataModel;
    }

    public void setLazyDataModel(LazyDataModel<User> lazyDataModel) {
       this.lazyDataModel = lazyDataModel;
    }

   //setters and getters for userEJB
}
```

***LazyUserModel***

```
public class LazyUserModel extends LazyDataModel<User> {
   private Integer findAllCount;

   @EJB
   private UserEJB userEJB;

   public LazyUserModel(UserEJB userEJB) {
       this.userEJB = userEJB;
   }


   @Override
   public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, String> filters) {

       List<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();
       // pageSize is scrollRows="20" in the datatable
       data = userEJB.findAll(first, pageSize); 
       // findAll is using query.setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList()

      // rowCount
       if (findAllCount == null) {
           findAllCount = userEJB.findAllCount();
           this.setRowCount(findAllCount);
       }

       return data;
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hatem for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: :I found issue with your solution.I have posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22249548/2805572).Can you please have a look at it.

Comment: Hey Hatim! Can you plz explain why we should to set RowCount and what is purpose? tnx

Comment: @anass it's the total number of records, this would be helpful for the pagination (pages navigator), in this case in the liveScroll I'm not sure if it's required to be set, haven't tried to eliminate the call.. nevertheless it's a good practice to keep things similar in case you might go back to pagination

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a new attribute for it in 6.1, liveScroll="true"
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2105