# Adding one or more outputText to existing page dynamically

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a need to continuously update a page with new data produced by managedbeans. Managedbean creates a new List of values for every few minutes and UI must create a OutputText for each of the value in the newly created List by managedbean. Catch is, the UI should retain the outputTexts and add new one's for every request, it should not refresh/remove old outputTexts.

My code is like below - updates the same outputText fields for each ajax call, which I need to change like mentioned above.

```
<c:forEach var="data" items="#{myBean.dataList}">
    <p:fieldset legend="#{data}" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" border="0">
            <p:scrollPanel style="height:300px">
               <p:poll interval="2" listener="#{myBean.getDataList}" update="field1 field2"/>
                   <h:outputText value="#{data.field1}" id="field1"/>
                   <h:outputText value="#{data.field2}" id="field2"/>
            </p:scrollPanel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
 </c:forEach>
```

so for each ajax call, there may be few data items produced by managedbeans and for each of those item there should be a new outputText field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datalist for `<h:outputText value="#{data.field1}" id="field1"/>`

Make a list and use them as outputtext, yes you need some css formatting because datalist used default css. sample code

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{yourbean.yourmethod}" update="<updatecomponet>" />
<p:dataList value="#{yourbean.tempList}" var="s" id="updatecomponet">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{s}"></p:outputLabel>
</p:dataList>
```

Note: You need to add value in list when poll call listener. it is working in my project, let me know for anything else. Hope this will help.

Comment: But whole dataList will be updated for every ajax call right? which might affect the performance badly over few hundreds of data items.

Comment: you have to update view if you need to add any new outputlabel right?. if not their is no way to add any thing new in view without fire update, for performance you can update datalist only when it needed, you can check in back bean and update from bean when it needed. if you got any solution let me know i also want the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the perfect solution, but you can use a DataTable with lazy loading, the poll component can update the datatable page and you don't need to update a huge amount of components.

Edit:
**xhtml**

```
 <p:dataTable var="v" 
     value="#{myBean.getLazyList}" 
     scrollRows="1" 
     liveScroll="true" 
     rows="20" 
     scrollHeight="300" 
     lazy="true" 
     scrollable="true" 
     id="tsUpdates">
            <p:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{v.fields1}" />
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Bean**

```
public class Bean {
    private LazyDataModel<MyClass> lazyList;

    @Named("myBean")
    @ViewScoped

    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
           lazyList = new LazyMyClassModel();  //where myList is your data source
        }

    //getters and setters    
}
```

**LazyModel**

```
    public class LazyMyClassModel extends LazyDataModel<MyClass>{
    private Integer findAllCount;

    public LazyMyClassModel(){

    }

    @Override
    public List<MyClass> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,Map<String, String> filters){
        List<MyClass> myList = //your live source of data
        List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        data = getSubList(MyList, first, pageSize)

        if (findAllCount == null) {
           findAllCount = myList.size
           this.setRowCount(findAllCount);
       }
       return data
    }

    public List<MyClass> getSubList(List<MyClass> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        int size = list.size();
        if (fromIndex >= size || toIndex <= 0 || fromIndex >= toIndex) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, fromIndex);
        toIndex = Math.min(size, toIndex);
        return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me overview of how to do it?

Comment: coz, I tried the below way,  <p:dataTable var="v"     value="#{myBean.getList}"  scrollRows="1"  liveScroll="true"  rows="20"     scrollHeight="300"    lazy="true"     scrollable="true"     id="tsUpdates">    <p:column> <h:outputText value="#{v.fields1}" /> </p:column></p:dataTable> ...

Comment: ...My backing bean's dataList will be empty initially and after sometime it will start producing the data...so with the above code, the table is not loading at all automatically when the datalist has somevalue. After manual refresh of webpage, it seems to load some data upon scolling, but even that loading stops at some point.. I don't know why and I couldn't understand the behaviour the the code clearly.

Comment: You're using live scrolling, but it's the same principle.  There is already a question about that, check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194987/is-primefaces-live-scrolling-compatible-with-lazy-loading

That example fetch 20 rows every time, you need a LazyModel class, extending the LazyDataModel abstract class, and to override the load() method.  Gonna edit my answer with some example code.